# I need a font name for clock for iphone?

Tags: iphone, fonts, clock

I want to see the font like [image]

I want something like as above, what is that, two labels or something else and what font is this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
[yourLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DBLCDTempBlack" size:42.0]];
```

Comment: It works, but I downloaded a DS Digital Theme, that is quit better, although I do accept your answer, not the above, because the above files are not properly working, Happy Coding :-)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.dafont.com/ds-digital.font

Kindly Check above font link.You can add these font in your App.BAsically these are two font.

Comment: but how can i add these ttf file to my app